# How to build Windows server 2003 in Win10?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server

Same with Title, I'm searching for "how to built 'Windows server 2003?'" Microsoft site doesn't exist Windows server 2003 but only Windows server 2016 and Windows server 2019 exist.
Of course, I can use 2016 or 2019 but In the book, I'm reading using 2003.

please help me how to build Windows server 2003

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "build". The traditional meaning implies you have the source code for Windows Server 2003 that you cannot compile on Windows 10.

Comment: If your meaning by "build" is virtualization OS, you have to install VMware and download Windows Server 2003 image.ISO from internet.